# Redirect an url to another url with apache

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I've a simple question, so here it is.
I was wondering how to make a simple redirection, I've wamp installed on my computer and I wish I could do that:
When I go to abc.com it redirect to xyz.com.
I did this in the httpd.conf file .. But it isn't working

```
   <VirtualHost *:80 >

    ServerName abc.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.xyz.com/

    </VirtualHost>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did your Apache load mod_alias? And, did you reload/restart your Apache after making these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable loggin (CustomLog,ErrorLog) and provide that output information. I'm using same kind of redirect and it works for me no problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems to work, but only when I go to http://localhost/ . However, what I want is that when I go to abc.com it goes to xyz.com.. And I can't do that..